# Conformal map $\mathbb{C} \setminus (\{ z \mid \mathrm{Im}(z) \leq 0\} \cup\{z = x+ iy \mid y \geq \sqrt{x^2 + 1}, x \leq 0\})$ onto unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry, geometric-transformation

> For figure $\mathbb{C} \setminus (\{ z \mid\mathrm{Im}(z) \leq 0\} \cup\{z = x+ iy \mid y \geq \sqrt{x^2 + 1}, x \leq 0\})$ find   a conformal mapping to closed unit disk.

What I have done so far: I found a conformal map from this figure to
$$\mathbb{C} \setminus (\{z \mid \mathrm{Im}z = 0, \mathrm{Re}z \leq 0 \} \cup \{z \mid \mathrm{Im}(z) \geq 0, \mathrm{Re}(z) \geq 1\}).$$
Then I tried to use Schwarz-Christoffel theorem but I'm stuck, because I have two vertices in infinity. However, I think I need the last step, and it can be done without Schwarz-Christoffel theorem...

Comment: If we take the angle between two lines at infinity to be minus the angle at their other intersection point, then the Schwarz-Christoffel formula remains unchanged for polygons with several vertices at infinity. So the angles should be $-\pi, 3 \pi/2, -\pi/2, 2 \pi$. A polygon with the two parallel rays lying on the same line (that is, equivalent to yours up to rotation and scaling) is given by
$$\int \frac {dz} {(z + 3)^{-1} (z + 1)^2 z^{-1/2}}.$$